# py2exe executable crashing in a seemingly random way

Tags: python, windows, crash, py2exe

I am writing a python script that monitors a folder for new files and then copies the files to a directory.  The code works perfectly when ran as a .py file, however, the executable created by py2exe loops for a while before stopping cleanly.  The crash cannot be caught by a try bracket.

A colleague of mine who was writing the same type of application in C++ with Qt was having a very similar issue.

I have not included the source code, because i didn't think it would be particularly useful, however if you disagree, I will post it.

I am using shutil for copying and os for listing directories and playing with file paths.
I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried removing everything from the loop except for a one second sleep and it still crashes

Comment: Are you trying to run the executable on the same PC as the script? If you were trying to run it on a 32-bit PC then there can be issues if py2exe has bundled 64-bit dlls. Failing that I think you'd need to post the source code (and probably the setup.py)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the appropriate DLLs and possibly their manifest with the executable created by py2exe as listed on [py2exe Tutorial Step 5](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5)? Without these the standalone will not run on any other computer, and depending on the version of Python in use py2exe cannot bundle these for you automatically.

Yes, I realize this is an old question.